# Jest unit tests throws "Unknown option" in build process

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm trying to execute Jest unit testing on a PWA made with Vue 2 but throws me an error when I try to build it. The error when i run `npm run build` is the following:
[image: Error screenshot]
The error prevents me to build and run the app.
The conflict is in the "test" property of the .babelrc file but if I remove this property, my tests stop working but the build works correctly.

My .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": [ "istanbul" ]
    }
  },
  "test": [
    "jest"
  ]
}
```

My babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
};
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ponce",
  "version": "1.3.1",
  "description": "ponce",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "android-init": "npx cap copy && npx cap add android",
    "android": "npm run build && npx cap copy && npx cap copy android && npx cap open android",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.3.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.5",
    "apollo-cache-persist": "^0.1.1",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.8",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.16",
    "buffer-browserify": "^0.2.5",
    "c3": "^0.7.15",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-socket-tcp": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
    "luxon": "^1.24.1",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.45.0",
    "node-gyp": "^7.1.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-browser-geolocation": "^1.8.0",
    "vue-datetime": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
    "vue-router": "^2.8.1",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7",
    "vue2-timepicker": "^1.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.14",
    "vuex": "^2.5.0",
    "vuex-persist": "^2.2.0",
    "weekstart": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.0",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "uglify-es": "^3.0.25",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-cli-plugin-apollo": "^0.21.3",
    "vue-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

I tried to look in the documentation but there it recognizes the option "test" in the .babelrc file.